# Adding multiple extra labels to decision tree of igraph

Tags: r, label, igraph, decision-tree

Assume a decision tree visualized via the R package `igraph`.

```
library(igraph)
n_of_vertices = 31
g = graph.tree(n_of_vertices, 2)
edge_labels = rep(c("Yes","No"), times=n_of_vertices/2)
plot(g,
    layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=1),
    asp=0.5,
    vertex.shape="square",
    vertex.label=NA,
    vertex.size=6,
    vertex.color="black",
    vertex.frame.color="white",
    edge.width=3,
    edge.arrow.mode=0,
    edge.label=edge_labels,
    edge.label.family="sans",
    edge.label.color="black",
    edge.label.cex=0.75)
```

I am looking for a way to add additional labels to the left of each vertex row, stating, for example, "Decision 1", "Decision 2", etc. I added such labels in red font to the example below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `text` function.

```
## Your tree plot
plot(g,
    layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=1),
    asp=0.5,
    vertex.shape="square",
    vertex.label=NA,
    vertex.size=6,
    vertex.color="black",
    vertex.frame.color="white",
    edge.width=3,
    edge.arrow.mode=0,
    edge.label=edge_labels,
    edge.label.family="sans",
    edge.label.color="black",
    edge.label.cex=0.75)

text(x=-1.2, y=c(0.5, 0, -0.5), 
    labels=c("Decision 1", "Decision 2", "Decision 3"),
    col="red")
```

[image: Labeled picture]

One of the tricks here is to decide *where* to place the text.  How did I get x,y coordinates to place the labels?   I used `locator`.  That allows you to simply click on a spot on the graph and find its coordinates. You may need to adjust slightly or use `cex` to adjust the font size.

Comment: A simple and clear solution! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`magickr` can be used to manipulate the plot and annotate with text.

```
library(igraph)
library(magick)

n_of_vertices = 31
g = graph.tree(n_of_vertices, 2)
edge_labels = rep(c("Yes","No"), times=n_of_vertices/2)

fig <- image_graph(width = 600, height = 600, res = 96)
#img <- image_draw(frink)

plot(g,
     layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=1),
     asp=0.5,
     vertex.shape="square",
     vertex.label=NA,
     vertex.size=6,
     vertex.color="black",
     vertex.frame.color="white",
     edge.width=3,
     edge.arrow.mode=0,
     edge.label=edge_labels,
     edge.label.family="sans",
     edge.label.color="black",
     edge.label.cex=0.75)

dev.off()

out <- fig %>% 
  image_annotate("Decision Tree", size = 20, color = "black",
                              degrees = 0, location = "+250+100") 


print(out)
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot recreate the solution you are proposing. When using the code you provide, all I receive is a blank image with the text "Decision tree". That text is not overlaying the decision tree.